# how to set tree view in dynamic menu in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

Hello guyyz i need help in design,i don't have ideas about design, i have created dynamic menu in codeigniter i want to set that menu in treeview.
First click on parent menu after open child menus, so how to implement it help me

Here is My View Code:

```
<?php
    foreach ($test as $val) {
      $array = explode(",", $val->category_id);
    }
    foreach ($get_cat as $key => $value) {
       if (in_array($value->category_id, $array)) {
         echo $value->category_name . '&nbsp;&nbsp;';  //Here My Menu Print
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I got solution of dynamic menu design in CodeIgniter:

```
 <?php
    //GET CATEGORY ID FROM USER REGISTARTION
    foreach ($test as $val) {
        $array = explode(",", $val->category_id);

        //CATEGORY ID MATCH WITH CATEGORY NAME FROM CATEGORY TABLE
        foreach ($listMenuLevel1 as $key => $value) {
            if (in_array($value->category_id, $array)) {
                ?>  
                <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                    <li class="treeview">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-share"></i> <span><?php echo $value->category_name; ?></span> 
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="treeview-menu">

                            <?php foreach ($this->main_model->listchildMenus($value->category_id) as $menu2) : ?>
                                <li class="treeview">
                                    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?><?php echo $menu2->category_link; ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i><?php echo $menu2->category_name; ?><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>

                                    <?php foreach ($this->main_model->listchildMenus($menu2->category_id) as $menu3): ?>
                                        <ul class="treeview-menu"> 
                                            <li class="treeview">
                                                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?><?php echo $menu3->category_link; ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i><?php echo $menu3->category_name; ?></a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch all category with `parent_id=0` then fetch subCategory. Try something like given below.

```
public function get_categories(){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('categories');
        $this->db->where('parent_id', 0);
        //Add here role condition
        $parent = $this->db->get();

        $categories = $parent->result();
        $i=0;
        foreach($categories as $p_cat){

            $categories[$i]->sub = $this->sub_categories($p_cat->cat_id);
            $i++;
        }
        return $categories;
    }
```

Your subcategory function.

```
public function sub_categories($id){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('categories');
        $this->db->where('parent_id', $id);
         //add here role condition
        $child = $this->db->get();
        $categories = $child->result();
        $i=0;
        foreach($categories as $p_cat){

            $categories[$i]->sub = $this->sub_categories($p_cat->cat_id);
            $i++;
        }
        return $categories;       
    }
```

And your controller.

```
public function categories(){

        $this->load->model('model_categories');
    $data = $this->model_categories->get_categories();

    print_r($data);
    }
```

Comment: Actually my menu is a role-wise display, here your menu role-wise display?

Comment: could you explain properly

Comment: My menu control is role wise display in view part, menu data fetch from single table

Comment: Role like Admin,HR,Accountant

Comment: you can add another condition or with session data

Comment: Can you give me little example please

Comment: I think the user must log in before seeing anything right

Comment: First user will login after menu display

Comment: You need to get logged in user id and add condtion like this :$this->db->where('role', $this->session->userdata('session_id'));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177401/discussion-between-jaydev-vara-and-rahul-shrivastava).